# Main menu help (pygame)

Tags: python, menu, pygame, rect

I have created mouse clicking functions to print (start, options and about) when I click those buttons. I just don't know how to go to the next stage of actually opening a new page once clicking those buttons. I had a go with trying to screen.fill when clicking the button but it would only last a couple of seconds and buttons would appear in front of it.

I am fairly new to pygame. 
Here is my code so far,

```
import pygame
from pygame import *


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
HOVER_COLOR = (50, 70, 90)

#Background Music
pygame.mixer.music.load('game.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(15)

#Background
bg = pygame.image.load("greybackground.png")


#Fonts
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman", 60)


text1 = FONT.render("START", True, WHITE)
text2 = FONT.render("OPTIONS", True, WHITE)
text3 = FONT.render("ABOUT", True, WHITE)

#Buttons
rect1 = pygame.Rect(300,300,205,80)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(300,400,205,80)
rect3 = pygame.Rect(300,500,205,80)

buttons = [
    [text1, rect1, BLACK],
    [text2, rect2, BLACK],
    [text3, rect3, BLACK],
    ]

running = False

def game_intro():
    while not running: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                    if button[1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                        button[2] = HOVER_COLOR
                    else:
                        button[2] = BLACK

                        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        for text, rect, color in buttons:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
            screen.blit(text, rect)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if rect1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                    elif rect2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print ('options')
                    elif rect3.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print ('about')

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_UP):
                    print ("UP was pressed")
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
                    print ("DOWN was pressed")
                elif (event.key == K_w):
                    print ("W was pressed")
                elif (event.key == K_s):
                    print ("S was pressed")
                else:
                    print ("error")




            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)



game_intro()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to do a similar thing myself. This is what you would put at the bottom:

```
while running:
event = pygame.event.wait()
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    if event.button == 1:
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 300 <= x <= 505 and 300 <= y <= 380:
            #change stuff here
            running = False

#insert code here \/ for the next screen
```

This can be used universally for every button. If you need more buttons, just copy and paste the third if statment and change as needed.

Don't forget to do 'pygame.display.update()' to refresh the screen; else, you will see nothing change (which is what happened to me).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you see my current code above and implement your code into mine as im extremely confused haha. i know im an idiot